# Part time Phd- Does it count negative in the path to becoming a Professor?

Tags: phd, career-path, germany

If some do a part-time PhD in Germany and work as full time in a research institute? Will it count as negative to become a professor.

Comment: Do you work in the research institute as a researcher, i.e with publications etc.? Then I cannot believe anyone sees this as a negative (note that many phds in Germany are, in fact, officially part-time).

Comment: The only negative thing I could think of is that you might not have as  much teaching experience. A few institutions might care about that.

Comment: So many other factors to be looked at on your application...

Comment: Yes, I work as a researcher, my tasks to publish one paper in a year. I am also involved in supervising research project and Bachelor and Master thesis. Do we only count teaching experience if I involved in some lecture or seminar?

Comment: @user111388: and even that may not be the case. I've been a postdoc at a German research institute which had anyways tight connections to the local university. I've been "lent out" to the local university to teach, other colleagues have also been teaching at the local university of applied sciences, and as student I also had lecturers from local research institutions outside the university. And of course the research institute will have students doing their research practica and all kinds of theses there.

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX: Indeed.

Comment: @AlexKujur: for a PhD student, also TAing a labwork practicum and looking after research students (or bachelor/master students) would usually count. Not the same as lecturing, but at least where I am, lectures were typically postdoc upwards. A PhD studend may be TA in a seminar.

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX Okay, thank you :)

Comment: I think the hardest part (in most fields) will be to develop a competitive publication record, compared to your peers. That's, of course, inherently harder when you have less time and energy to develop your papers. The recommendation would be to see what types and numbers of papers other people have who recently got a professor job in your field.

Comment: I do not understand the constellation here. What exactly does "do a part-time PhD"  mean here? Is this unrelated to your full position and you are working on a self-funded PhD project in your free time?

Comment: @Roland yes, will it affect on future? Is it good to show both working details in my CV?

Comment: As long as your PhD project is high quality research and you get awarded the PhD, I don't see any downsides. For becoming a professor, the subsequent steps in your career are far more important. It also depends on where you want to become a professor. A German *Fachhochschule* values industry experience at least as much as academic experience.

Comment: @Roland Thanks, yes, I am aiming for University, not for Fachhochschule, I understand its a long run but just want to make sure, it won't make any negative in my profile.

Answer (score 3):

A PhD is a PhD... it doesn't matter how long it takes, or whether it is full or part-time, the qualification itself is unaffected.

Amount of research produced over a certain duration has got some importance though.

The crucial question is the **reason** for the PhD being part-time. If that reason would reflect badly on your perceived fit as an academic, then it might have a bearing (if it implies too many family commitments, or lack of motivation perhaps).

However the fact that your full-time work is, you say, in a research institute is great for you in this regard. Your full time work is directly related to one of the roles of an academic. As such this should have no negative bearing whatsoever on the path to becoming a professor.

Comment: Employers should not discriminate based on family commitments.

Comment: Employers don't care about PhD duration, but the student should.  Completing the PhD promptly is good for the student's finances.

Comment: Thanks, will it affect in future If I show 2 experiences in my CV?

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist they shouldn't, but it's possible that they could